# Python: Best way to hold and check if two logos are same irrelevant to their orientation

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

So in the programme, I take commands from user about logo shape that will be carved into 11x11 square like this: LOGO logoname1 DDRUL. DDRUL stands for
D as in Down,
U as in up,
R as in right
L as in left.
Since logonames are unique, I hold logos in a dictionary as keys and their corresponding values are their directions held as lists like ('D','R','U','L').

The system should identify two logos as the same if their shape is the same irrespective of their orientatio i.e., we may turn a logo engraved surface 90◦, 180◦, and 270◦clockwise (or counter-clockwise) when comparing with another logo.
For instance;
a logo that has the directions of URDUDDLL and a different logo with directions DDRRUL should be identified as the same like in these images: [logo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf3Db.png)
[logo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qqT6.png)

I dont know how to check this functionality with the way I am keeping everything and appreciate any thought or help.

Comment: Define a canonical representation for a logo and write a function which converts the user given logo to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain a bit more on how to represent them in canonical form, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with it. @mkrieger1

Comment: I'm also not familiar with it because you need to invent it first.